# How to show decimal value separately in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `c_price` and have a column value like below in PostgreSQL.

| st_price |
| --- |
| 100.25 |
| 102.25 |

Now need a query for below result.

| st_price | p1 | p2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.25 | 100 | 25 |
| 102.26 | 102 | 26 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trunc()` and `mod()` may be used

> ```
> select trunc(123.67) as dollars, trunc(mod(123.67*100,100)) as cents
> ```
>
> ```
> dollars | cents
> ------: | ----:
>     123 |    67
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a3aeaafb9de8474b005162a680d32b57)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - **[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=35ac90b85d066144afc32eb14518e40a)**

```
select st_price,
   st_price::int as p1,
   substring((st_price-st_price::int)::text,position('.' in (st_price-st_price::int)::text)+1) as p2
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is to use:

```
select st_price, trunc(st_price)as p1, st_price % 1 as p2
from c_price;
```

The modulo operator `%` returns the fraction part of number when used with a second argument of `1`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ba0a05fcd4d5a301b1b853f20bbaa3b0) is a db<>fiddle.